# What is proper way of using xlPasteSpecial.Values?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to remove formulas from a range of cells so that only values are kept.

I am using `Excel.Interop`

I've recorded VBA macro (simply copying all and pasting the special values) and did the same in `C#` with following code:

```
xlWorkSheet.Activate();
    xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Z"].Copy();
    xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents();
    xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Z"].Select();
    xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Z"].PasteSpecial(
       Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
       Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
       System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'PasteSpecial method of Range class failed'

Answer (score 0):

Figured out :

```
    xlWorkSheet.Activate();
    xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Z"].Select();
    xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy();
    xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Z"].PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
```